# Angular 7 Bootstrap Modal - show dynamic content

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, modal-dialog

My changeDetector is not updating the view when there is a new value.

**parent.component.html**

```
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center loading-div" *ngIf="_isLoading">
    <div class="typing-spinner">
        <div class="ball hu-background-color_accent"></div>
        <div class="ball hu-background-color_accent"></div>
        <div class="ball hu-background-color_accent"></div>
    </div><br><br>
    Loading...
</div>
<section class="screen-three">
    <div class="screen-content">
        <div class="bk-chat-bubble">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="bk-chat left">
                    <div class="bk-message col-9 col-md-10 offset-3 offset-md-2">
                        <figure class="bk-avtar"></figure>
                        <div class="bubble-text">
                            <h2 class="mt-0">Careers</h2>
                            <p>Subtitle to careers, taking up two lines</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="career-list pb-1">
            <div class="container">
                <div *ngIf="_careers; else showLoading" class="careers-grid">
                    <div class="row career-item" *ngIf="_careers.length == 0">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h3 class="text-center">No records found</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row career-item" *ngFor="let career of _careers">
                        <div class="col-8 col-md-12 p-0">
                            <h3 class="m-0">{{ career.name }}</h3>
                            <!-- Start: For Desktop only -->
                            <span class="bk-number d-none d-md-inline-block">
                                {{ career.meanSalaryDiff | roundOffNearestHundred : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0' }}
                                <i class="delta up"></i>
                            </span>
                            <!-- End: For Desktop only -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- Start: For mobile only -->
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-12 p-0 text-right text-md-left d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">
                            <span class="bk-number">
                                {{ career.meanSalaryDiff | roundOffNearestHundred : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0' }}
                                <i class="delta up"></i>

                            </span>
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="text-link" (click)="showModal(career.name)">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End: For mobile only -->

                        <!-- Start: For Desktop only -->
                        <a href="#" class="text-link d-none d-md-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Learn More</a>
                        <!-- End: For Desktop only -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ng-template #showLoading>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center careers-loading"><i class="fas fa-spinner fast-spin"></i></div>
                </ng-template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Modal window code -->
<app-modal [careerDetails]="careerDetails"></app-modal>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

import { AppService } from '../../_services/app.service';

// Include helpers
import { RoundOffNearestHundredPipe } from '../../_helpers/round-off-nearest-hundred.pipe';

declare var $;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user-career-overview',
    templateUrl: './user-career-overview.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-career-overview.component.scss']
})
export class UserCareerOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input('careers') _careers: any = [];
    _isLoading = false;
    careerDetails: any;

    constructor(private _appService: AppService) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    showModal(designation: string) {
        this._isLoading = true;
        const params = {
            designation
        };
        this._appService.getCareerDetails(params)
            .subscribe(careerDetail => {
                this._isLoading = false;
                this.careerDetails = careerDetail;
                $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            },
            error => {});
    }
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content bk-modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-body bk-modal">
                <div class="col-11 p-0">
                    <h1 class="mt-0">{{ _careerDetail?.name }}</h1>
                </div>
                <p class="mt-5 pb-5">{{ _careerDetail?.description }}</p>
                <h2 class="mt-3 mb-0">Top Skills</h2>
                <div class="skill-carousel v-list">
                    <ul class="skill-slides">
                        <li class="skill-item">
                            <div class="skill-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-8">
                                        <h3 class="mt-0">Project <br>Management</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start: Skill Levels Visualizations -->
                                    <div class="col-4 pl-0 text-right">
                                        <!-- Three dots = {necessary skills+specialized skills} -->
                                        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <circle cx="4" cy="20" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                            <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                            <circle cx="12" cy="4" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End: Skill Levels Visualizations -->
                                </div>
                                <p>Text changes to be something slightly more promotional for the courses below lorem
                                    ipsum three lines.</p>
                                <a class="text-link bk-chevron courses-trigger collapsed" data-text="Learn Public Management"
                                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#leran01-courses">
                                    Learn Project Management
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Skill 1 - Courses -->
                            <div id="leran01-courses" class="collapse">
                                <ul class="courses-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/udemy-logo.svg" alt="Udemy">
                                        <a href="https://www.udemy.com/courses/business/project-management/" target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore
                                        <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/coursera.svg" alt="Coursera">
                                        <a href="https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=project-management" target="_blank"
                                            class="jumplink">Explore <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/skillshare-logo.svg" alt="Skillshare">
                                        <a href="https://www.skillshare.com/search?query=Project%20Management"
                                            target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="skill-item">
                            <div class="skill-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-8">
                                        <h3 class="mt-0">Brand <br>Strategy</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start: Skill Levels Visualizations -->
                                    <div class="col-4 pl-0 text-right">
                                        <!-- Four dots = {distinguishing skills+differentiating skills} -->
                                        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                            <circle cx="20" cy="4" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                            <circle cx="4" cy="20" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                            <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End: Skill Levels Visualizations -->
                                </div>
                                <p>Max three lines blurb that explains this skill, brand strategy, and why it’s good
                                    for your career.</p>
                                <a class="text-link bk-chevron courses-trigger collapsed" data-text="Learn Brand Strategy"
                                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#leran02-courses">
                                    Learn Brand Strategy
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Skill 2 - Courses -->
                            <div id="leran02-courses" class="collapse">
                                <ul class="courses-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/udemy-logo.svg" alt="Udemy">
                                        <a href="https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=Brand%20Strategy" target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore
                                            <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/coursera.svg" alt="Coursera">
                                        <a href="https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=Brand%20Strategy" target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore
                                            <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/skillshare-logo.svg" alt="Skillshare">
                                        <a href="https://www.skillshare.com/search?query=Brand%20Strategy"
                                            target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="skill-item">
                            <div class="skill-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-8">
                                        <h3 class="mt-0">Public <br>Relations</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Start: Skill Levels Visualizations -->
                                    <div class="col-4 pl-0 text-right">
                                        <!-- Two dots = {baseline skills} -->
                                        <svg width="24" height="8" viewBox="0 0 24 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                            <circle cx="20" cy="4" r="4" fill="#394BEA"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End: Skill Levels Visualizations -->
                                </div>
                                <p>Max three lines blurb that explains this skill, brand strategy, and why it’s good
                                    for your career.</p>
                                <a class="text-link bk-chevron courses-trigger collapsed" data-text="Learn Public Relations"
                                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#leran03-courses">
                                    Learn Public Relations
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Skill 3 - Courses -->
                            <div id="leran03-courses" class="collapse">
                                <ul class="courses-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/udemy-logo.svg" alt="Udemy">
                                        <a href="https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=Public%20Relations" target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore
                                            <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/coursera.svg" alt="Coursera">
                                        <a href="https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=Public%20Relations"
                                            target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="../../../assets/images/skillshare-logo.svg" alt="Skillshare">
                                        <a href="https://www.skillshare.com/search?query=Public%20Relations"
                                            target="_blank" class="jumplink">Explore <i class="jumplink"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() careerDetails: any;
    _careerDetail: any;

    constructor(private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (!changes.careerDetails.firstChange) {
            this._careerDetail = changes.careerDetails.currentValue;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Problem: I am recieving the data from my service and I can console.log it inside ngOnChanges function of child.component.ts

However the updated data is not being updated in the view.

Am I implementing the Onchanges function incorrectly?
Any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad.

I had an extra child of  in parent's parent view, which was not used. Hence deleting it solved the issue.